# Какой кратчайший путь к карьере Android разработчика?

Tags: android, книги, задание-на-собеседовании

Читал и смотрел много материалов на эту тему, и мнения часто кардинально противоположные. Кто-то говорит, что опираться нужно в основном на книги, с самого начала и до конца, кто-то, что наоборот практика первична, а книги имеет смысл читать, только в качестве материала, способного улучшить твоё понимание вопроса (в противном случае, по данному мнению, потраченной время не стоит весьма скромного итогового результата).
Небольшое пояснение: Я нахожусь не совсем в начале пути, программирую чуть больше года, за то время изучал программирование на JavaRush, читал книгу Head First "Программируем на Java", освоил часть книги этого же издательства на тему Android разработки, написал несколько приложений (в основном под Android), побывал на 5 собеседованиях (не все на Android разработчика), провалил несколько тестовых заданий.
Сейчас читаю книгу "Android программирование для профессионалов" и выполняю просроченные тестовые задания.

Главная проблема в том, что даже спустя год программирования мне не удалось создать оптимальную стратегию обучения, в связи с этим я спрашиваю Вас, как более опытных товарищей, какой способ обучения Вы считаете наиболее эффективным и почему?

Comment: Вам надо не стратегию обучения создавать, а работающие приложения.

Comment: Наиболее эффективный способ - это найти учителя, но это практически не реально. Поэтому рекомендую книгу в которой теоретический материал излагается как создание практических приложений. "Андроид для разработчиков" Пол Дейтел и другие.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, то, что я сейчас напишу, верно не только для Android - разработчика, а для любой профессиональной сферы в принципе.

Книги, статьи и курсы - это замечательная вещь, однако их можно разделить на две категории:

1. Для новичков. Опишут и немного раскроют свою тему, дадут основу. Никак не позволят стать профессионалом. Изучив останетесь новичком, хотя и чуть более знающим.
2. Для профессионалов. Используются для развития специалистами своего дела. Они не позволяют новичкам стать профи. Но профи с их помощью становятся лучше.

То есть в целом интернет-ресурсы могут улучшить Ваш текущий уровень, но не продвинуть Вас на следующую крупную ступень.

Для того же, чтобы стать действительно полноценным специалистом Вам необходим опыт. Работа с людьми, значительно лучше разбирающимися в теме. Передача опыта и знаний при общении вживую проходит намного быстрее, чем через текст или видео. И если более опытный коллега будет чему-то Вас учить, то он не будет строить объяснение для огромной аудитории, а постарается рассказать так, чтобы было понятно именно Вам. Ну и нельзя забывать, что работая в команде Вы будете не только писать свой код, но и читать код других (и читать придется намного больше, чем писать). Чтение кода более опытных разработчиков, если Вы разрабатываете вместе с ними общее приложение, это один из лучших способов учебы.

В общем, самый сложный и важный шаг в карьере - получить первое место работы, желательно не удаленно (ведь нужен, в первую очередь, опыт, а он вживую передается быстрее). В подавляющем большинстве случаев, к сожалению, первая работа будет весьма низкооплачиваемой, однако, через 6-12 месяцев из начинающего Вы уже станете молодым специалистом и отрыв в знаниях от того уровня, который есть сейчас, будет колоссальным.

Comment: Совершенно верно, хорошее программирование это в основном *"устное народное творчество"* -)

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо)

Answer (score 5):

Я хоть и не Senior разработчик, но поделюсь своей стратегией развития, которая как мне кажется очень сильно увеличивает уровень навыков: смотреть и анализировать open source проекты, коих на просторах гитхаба очень много. Скачиваешь такие проекты, запускаешь в студии и пытаешься понять что там происходит. Смотришь коммиты которые делали разработчики, что бы понять в какой последовательности делается проект. Непонятное гуглишь. 
Успехов вам

Comment: Премного благодарен!)